# Unfollowing friends, groups, pages on Facebook via Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/og.follows?locale=en_GB#unfollowing) it says you can unfollow someone by issuing an HTTP DELETE to the subscription ID. When I do that, I am being told I need access token. However, when I look through available apps permissions, I can't find any which would give permission to do such requests. Is it still possible to do or the docs are outdated?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it cannot be done anymore with 2nd version of Graph Api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends?locale=en_GB . Please let me know if you find otherwise.

Comment: Since this is an OG action, I would assume that you will need `publish_actions` permission for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That action is to unfollow a friend/user actions within an Open Graph application.

For example

[image: Og Facebook]

If I didn't want to follow Ola's actions within Social Cafe I will issue an HTTP DELETE.

This is **not** for unfollowing any object in the news feed.

Comment: Right. So I can unfollow person's feeds related to Social Cafe but not all of them?